# How to Bind Keyboard button to do other action in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bind

I want to know if it's possible to bind any keyboard key in windows to do a action.

The action I want is, when I press "?" then it just types a text "Hello, This is new world" Automatically. Is this possible? If so then please help me out.

Comment: how possible? what kind of effort should be put into a solution. anything is possible.

Comment: If you know any way then let me know ;)

Comment: it would be possible, though very difficult, to write a service (memory client) that hooks into the windows message stack and listens for key presses. Then act on those messages. You could choose to divert them or let them on their way. This is how key-loggers work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few places to start researching.

The functionality you are looking for is similar to the design of a key logger. the difference is you intend to consume the key as opposed to observe it and let it through

http://www.securelist.com/en/analysis/204792178/Keyloggers_Implementing_keyloggers_in_Windows_Part_Two

[C++ Custom hot keys using windows hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698616/c-custom-hot-keys-using-windows-hooks)

http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/132-keystroke-monitoring